# WordPress: Create Table of contents based on H2 headings as Gutenberg block

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, tableofcontents, gutenberg-blocks

I want to add a custom gutenberg block to add a table of contents to my article.
The ToC should generate links based on the H2 headings in the post.

At the moment the code is added to the post template itself and it works fine.

But if I add it to a custom Gutenberg block I get an error.

I guess it's not possible to us my current code because it uses the content of the post itself.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php

$content_postid = get_the_ID();
$content_post   = get_post($content_postid);
$content        = $content_post->post_content;
$content        = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content        = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

$content = $content;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//*[contains("h2", name())]';

$nodes = $xp->query($query);

$currentLevel = ['level' => 0, 'count' => 0];
$stack = [];
$format = '<a href="#%s" target="_self">%s</a>';
$result = '';

if ($nodes) {

    $result .= '<div">';

    foreach($nodes as $node) {

        $level = (int)$node->tagName[1]; // extract the digit after h

        while($level < $currentLevel['level']) {
            $currentLevel = array_pop($stack);
        }

        if ($level === $currentLevel['level']) {
            $currentLevel['count']++;
        } else {
            $stack[] = $currentLevel;
            $currentLevel = ['level' => $level, 'count' => 1];
        }

        $result .= sprintf($format, $node->getAttribute('id'), $currentLevel['level'], $currentLevel['count'], $node->nodeValue);

    }

    $result .= '</div>';

}

$result .= str_repeat('</ul>', count($stack));

echo $result;

?>
```

Is there any way to use that code inside the Gutenberg block or do I have to rewrite everything?

Comment: You could try creating a [dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/), that way you can reuse your existing PHP code (with some tweaks of course).